# Multiple Queries only the last one executing

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code below;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 where id_no = '$id_no'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $new = $row['full_name'];
       header("location:new.php?msg=ID Number $id is already 
      Registered");
    }
    } else {
      $created = date('jS \ F Y h:i:s A');
        $tr_no = 'TR_'.rand(10000,99999).'/'.date(Y).'';

    include '../db_config/connection.php';

    //update tables
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,vehicle_id,policy_id,insured_by,insurance_co,value_insured,start_date,end_date,created)VALUES ('$tr_no','$reg_no','$p_id','$user_index','$co_id','$value_insured','$start_date','$end_date','$created')" ;
    $sql =  "UPDATE tbl1 SET updated='1' WHERE item_id = '$reg_no'";
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO tbl3 (doc_number,value,date,reg_no) VALUES('$tr_no','-$value_insured','$created','$reg_no'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        header("location:new_insurance.php?message=ENTRIES SUCCESSFULLY POSTED");
    } else {
        $error = $conn->error;
         header("location:new_client.php?err=$error");
    }

    $conn->close();



    }
    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

The last bit that contains the insert and update queries is where am having the problem. Rather than executing all the three queries, only the last one is executed. What modifications should i include?

Comment: You override the content of `$sql`. You do not concat it

Comment: Which API do you use? `mysqli_` or `PDO`?

Comment: You need to use `mysqli_multi_query()` . Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Even if you concat (join together) the SQL strings you'll have problems as together they will product invalid SQL.

Either build and execute the strings one at a time, or contact them together after adding a ';' character (sql terminiator) to the end of each string

Answer (score 0):

First Change these statements (concatenates the $sql variable and add semicolon ';' at end of each statements.)

```
    $sql =  "INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,vehicle_id,policy_id,insured_by,insurance_co,value_insured,start_date,end_date,created) VALUES ('$tr_no','$reg_no','$p_id','$user_index','$co_id','$value_insured','$start_date','$end_date','$created');" ;
    $sql .=  "UPDATE tbl1 SET updated='1' WHERE item_id = '$reg_no';";
    $sql .=  "INSERT INTO tbl3 (doc_number,value,date,reg_no) VALUES('$tr_no','-$value_insured','$created','$reg_no');";
```

Now finally execute multiple queries by mysqli_multi_query()

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)) {   //con is your connection
        header("location:new_insurance.......
```

Comment: Please give me the full code for that page, because above mentioned code was not complete so I can not say where is mistake.

Comment: i modified the code and renamed the 3 ($sql)s to have unique values then added an if statement for each